# Failed validation during AJAX form submission breaks AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

Okay, so I have read through stackoverflow and various other portions of the net for a few days, and have not found a solution yet that fixes my issue.

Basically, I have an `h:form` in a `p:dialog` with two required fields. When the fields are both filled in, the form successfully submits and the dialog closes. When either or both fields are left blank, required field validation fails and updates the `h:messages` component in the `p:dialog` with the appropriate required messages. However, also when validation fails, the AJAX call seems to never "finish" and prevents subsequent calls from being executed. This is seen evident by my `p:ajaxStatus` component never disappearing from the screen, indicating that *something* is hanging *somewhere*. This is remedied by refreshing the page, at which point all other AJAX components begin to function again.

Additionally, I will note that this `p:dialog` is in a `ui:define` in a `ui:composition`, that dumps it into a master template. It is **not** nested within another `h:form`.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgDecision"
                  header="Decision"
                  widgetVar="dialogDecision"
                  modal="false"
                  resizable="false"
                  appendToBody="true">
            <h:form id="fDlgDecision">
                <h:messages id="msgDlgDecision" binding="#{msgform.messages}" errorClass="errormsg" infoClass="infomsg1" layout="table"/>
                <h:outputFormat rendered="#{studentdetailsform.decisionAction == 'A'}">
                    <h:outputText value="Select an accept and admit code."/>
                </h:outputFormat>
                <h:outputFormat rendered="#{studentdetailsform.decisionAction == 'C'}">
                    <h:outputText value="Select a cancel and reason code."/>
                </h:outputFormat>
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="apdcCode"
                                     value="#{studentDetails.apdcCode}"
                                     required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Please choose a decision code.">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Decision Code"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{apdcCodes.apdcCodeList}"
                                       var="apdc"
                                       itemValue="#{apdc.apdcCode}"
                                       itemLabel="#{apdc.apdcCode} - #{apdc.apdcDesc}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="admtCode"
                                     value="#{studentDetails.admtCode}"
                                     required="#{studentdetailsform.decisionAction == 'A'}"
                                     requiredMessage="Please choose an admit code."
                                     rendered="#{studentdetailsform.decisionAction == 'A'}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Admit Code"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{admtCodes.admtCodeList}"
                                       var="admt"
                                       itemValue="#{admt.admtCode}}"
                                       itemLabel="#{admt.admtCode} - #{admt.admtDesc}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="wrsnCode"
                                     value="#{studentDetails.wrsnCode}"
                                     required="#{studentdetailsform.decisionAction == 'C'}"
                                     requiredMessage="Please choose a reason code."
                                     rendered="#{studentdetailsform.decisionAction == 'C'}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Reason Code"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{wrsnCodes.wrsnCodeList}"
                                       var="wrsn"
                                       itemValue="#{wrsn.wrsnCode}"
                                       itemLabel="#{wrsn.wrsnCode} - #{wrsn.wrsnDesc}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:commandButton id="decisionSubmit"
                                     value="Submit Decision"
                                     type="submit"
                                     action="#{mainform.saveDecision}"
                                     ajax="true"
                                     partialSubmit="true"
                                     process="@form"
                                     update="@form msgDlgDecision"
                                     oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) dialogDecision.hide()"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

Some things I have already done in my debugging and troubleshooting:
- Moved the `h:form` into the `p:dialog`
- Made the backing bean with the values for the `rendered` attribute on the required fields `ViewScoped` (was having an issue with only some of the required messages showing, this resolved this problem)
- Added `appendToBody="true"` to `p:dialog`
- Added `if (!args.validationFailed)` to the `oncomplete` event of `p:dialog`
- Tried making the required fields NOT conditional (removed `rendered` attributes) to be sure this wasn't being caused by failed validation on non-rendered components (grasping at straws...)

**EDIT:** Here is a console dump from Chrome. Javascript error gets thrown when submitting the form with null required fields.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { jquery.js:14
bG.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:14
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.handleResponse primefaces.js:1
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse primefaces.js:1
j.success primefaces.js:1
bZ jquery.js:14
b7.fireWith jquery.js:14
ca jquery.js:21
bZ
```

**EDIT 2:** Below are the only two JavaScript imports, both of which are in my template that is applied to the page via the `ui:define` and `ui:composition` mentioned above.

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/scripts/jscript.js" />
```

The first import will force Primefaces to import jQuery into the page, even if there are no components on the page that utilize JavaScript. This is to allow my custom scripts in `jscript.js` to use jQuery reliably.

**Other information:**
JSF 2.1
Primefaces 3.4.2
Tomcat 6.0

Comment: For me this looks like JavaScript broke. Can you see JavaScript console an see is there error after submitting form with empty field(s)?

Comment: @partlov You would appear to be correct. I've updated the questions with the console dump. Curiously enough, other Javascript seems to work after this-- I can manually close the dialog, in addition to using some custom show/hide panels I've made elsewhere in the application. Just seems like anything Primefaces+JS/AJAX breaks. I can't resubmit the form with valid values for example, it just sits there.

Comment: Edit your question and add that. Looks like some JavaScript/jQuery conflict. Are you manually importing some JS library or possible jQuery?

Comment: @partlov Sorry, the editor was not playing nicely with that console dump. It is now in the main question.

Comment: Can you just provide answer on previous question about importing JavaScript? It can be reason for this.

Comment: @partlov Sorry. Didn't see that, I've added my JS imports with my explanation to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import jQuery.js manually as this is already done implicitly by PrimeFaces (it uses jQuery under the hood). You can remove that line.

Also you should see some examples of importing your custom js files with `h:outputScript` like this for example:

```
<h:outputScript library="scripts" name="jscript.js" />
```

but this is probably not reason of your problem, this is just hint for better JSF design.

Comment: Thanks. I realize it gets pulled in automatically, but only when there are Primefaces components that need access to it (at least this is my understanding). So, if you have a page with no Primefaces components, but custom JavaScript that uses jQuery, you do need this import. In any case, this application has turned into a single-view app with multiple dialogs and form submission exclusively done using AJAX. As such, I've removed the manual jQuery import, and reformatted by custom script import. Also, as you already stated-- this obviously does not fix the issue at hand.

Comment: No, I am receiving the same error as before. I even cleared my cookies/cache and re-opened Chrome to be sure the changes took.

Comment: Did you try with another browser, Firefox for example? Also see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4609)

Comment: The other issue you mentioned above was my solution, kind of. That issue has a patch for PrimePartialResponseWriter for Primefaces 3.4.2... I have never patched source code and built the jar myself, though it just seems to be a few commands in UNIX. In any event, I simply upgraded to Primefaces 3.5 and my `p:dialog` now functions as one would expect! I will have to experiment with patching in my spare time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A similar error showed up in Google Chrome, today, after I downloaded PrimeFaces 4.0 snapshot (2013-05-09) and tested my app.

Basically, I had to remove single quotes from data sent from bean to p:schedule via JSON. Since the error mentioned 'parse JSON' and "unexpected '" (unexpected single quote), I went to the datatable view of my data (instead of p:schedule) and recognized that some of the data had single quotes embedded. So, I removed the single quotes from the data, and that solved the issue for me.

Please click forum topic URL below.

[PF 4.0 SNAPSHOT 2013-05-09: schedule not working](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30283)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem at my application. The real problem was a duplicate jar problem.

I've had two primefaces jar in my application, one under the WEB-INF/lib directory, and the other under the ear/lib directory. Once I deleted the one under the WEB-INF, everything started to work as expected.

You could find the solution on the net via a search for the js exception.